# I would like to trigger an event when a checkbox is clicked

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, text, checkbox

```
Private Sub ShowPasswordButton_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ShowPasswordButton.CheckedChanged
    If ShowPasswordButton.Checked = True Then
        NewPassword.TextMode = TextBoxMode.SingleLine
    Else
        NewPassword.TextMode = TextBoxMode.Password
    End If
End Sub
```

I am trying to change text appearance when the box is checked, but checking the box does nothing. It doesn't trigger the event at all. I have this placed in the right spot and I would assume that it should run, but it isn't.

Comment: Psst: don’t write `= True` in a conditional. It’s redundant. Anyways, have you set a breakpoint?

Comment: I change the "= True" (kinda embarrassing). No, there aren't any breakpoints in my code.

Comment: Have you set AutoPostBack="True" in your "ShowPasswordButton" check box?

Comment: I dont have the reputation right now. :'( I will be glad to later.

Comment: no, you just have to click the checkmark below the downvote button..

Comment: @user3483317: accepting a question's answer can be done with any rep.

Comment: Sorry, i meant vote up. I already accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have the `AutoPostBack="True"` property in your checkbox to trigger a server side event.